# What does `exec <&-` do?

Tags: bash

Just editing a bash script and the last line is:

```
exec <&-
```

Hoping someone can explain.  I'm guessing it has to do with the exit code of the previous command?

Answer (score 0):

`exec <&-` closes standard input (filedescriptor `0`).

`exec` with just redirections but not other argument applies the redirections to the current process.

A redirection to or from `&-` means `close`.
With numerical descriptors it doesn't matter if you do `0<&-` or `0>&-` — either version will close filedescriptor `0` (standard input). If you ommit the number `>` redirection means "use fildescriptor 1`and`<` means "use filedescriptor 0".

Comment: To make this answer more generally useful, could you add links to the relevant parts of https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html ?

Comment: @ruakh I have since added an explanation. I'm not referencing the reference page, but it's info on the `&-` redirection is easy to find by `/` searching either `man sh` or `man bash` (the feature is POSIX compliant -- extensions like those of bash aren't needed for it to work).